# htaccess only works for one

Tags: htaccess

I currently use the following htaccess code to remove php extensions and also allow the /index.php page to load without the word "index":

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ $1.php [L]
```

I used to create a new page for every single user but as one could probably see, this is not such a good idea. So i deleted all the user pages and i would include them a different way but i would need to pass the requested page as a get parameter to another file. So I decided to route every main level (/) requested page through a file in a different directory, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ some/page.php?requested_page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But it does not work with the /index.php page if someone just requested it like this: /

i changed the code to:

```
RewriteRule ^(<?!)([^/]+)$ some/page.php?requested_page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

and now the "/" request works and any page that really exist works, but the "fake user pages" now dont work. is there way i can do both?

Comment: I have answered below, but I'm a bit confused by the regex in your fix attempt: `^(<?!)([^/]+)$` - I can't see how this would work at all, even for the `/` request? `(<?!)` looks like a parenthesised sub pattern that would match either `<!` or `!`? If you could explain that I would be very grateful. :)

Comment: to be quite honest im not quite sure why it would work either. hahah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ ....
```

This did not work for your index.php page when accessing as `/` since in that case the URL path is empty, but `+` matches 1 or more chars, so it doesn't match. Change `+` to `*` to match 0 or more.